# What program can I use to view a .gfa file?

Tags: image-format, gif

I have a `.gfa` file that needs viewing outside my simulation program.
After google-ing `.gfa`, I found that it belongs to the Graphics Interchange Format along with `.gif`.

But I have not found a viewer that can actually play this file.

This file is a like a regular `.gif` file, but, the image is moveable.
e.g. : In the file I have, I run an explosion simulation.  In the built-in `.gfa` viewer I can view the explosion from different angles.

So basically, its a `.gif` file, but cooler.  I just need a program that can view this file.

Comment: I can not find any reference that points to `.gfa` files being related to `.gif` files. Most hits indicated that it is either an MSDOS file or an ATARI Graphics file. All that said, it sounds like you're simply making an animated gif, which has the standard `.gif` extension and any web browser should be able to open it.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to graphicdesign.se. Could you specify what simulation program your using? This may help getting you a good aswer. 

File format extensions are by no mean universally standard and there may be many different **.gfa** formats. Be sure to check [about] and [help]

Answer (score 0):

.GFA is a motion capture format similar to .BVH files. They are used in a motion plugin called Animate2 and can be viewed inside a 3D animation program such as DAZ3D (free).